# How to use F1 Score with Keras model?

Tags: python, keras

For some reason I get error message when trying to specify f1 score with Keras model:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy', 'f1_score'])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function:f1_score
```

After providing 'f1_score' function in the same file where I use 'model.compile' like this:

```
def f1_score(y_true, y_pred):

    # Count positive samples.
    c1 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    c2 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    c3 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))

    # If there are no true samples, fix the F1 score at 0.
    if c3 == 0:
        return 0

    # How many selected items are relevant?
    precision = c1 / c2

    # How many relevant items are selected?
    recall = c1 / c3

    # Calculate f1_score
    f1_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    return f1_score 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy', f1_score])
```

Model compiles all right and can be saved to a file:

```
model.save(model_path) # works ok
```

Yet loading it in another program, :

```
from keras import models 
model = models.load_model(model_path)
```

fails with an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function:f1_score
```

Specifying 'f1_score' in the same file this time does not help, Keras does not see it. What's wrong? How to use F1 Score with Keras model?

Comment: What is `K` in your example code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you load the model, you have to supply that metric as part of the `custom_objects` bag.

Try it like this:

```
from keras import models 
model = models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects= {'f1_score': f1_score})
```

Where `f1_score` is the function that you passed through `compile`.

Answer (score 1):

For your implementation of `f1_score` to work I had to switch `y_true` and `y_pred` in the function declaration.
P.S.: for those who asked: `K = keras.backend`

Comment: "The function would need to take (y_true, y_pred) as arguments and return a single tensor value." - from [the docs](https://keras.io/metrics/)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
metrics=['accuracy', f1_score]
```

to:

```
metrics=[f1_score]
```